# Opennlp OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with 16GB RAM

Tags: out-of-memory, heap-memory, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run a twitter sentiment analysis with Java and got hands on a 1.6 million lines traningset, with each line having either a 0 or a 1 and a twitter text. The .csv is around 250 MB large.

I use OpenNLP for analyzing and try to train my model like this:

```
InputStream dataIn = new 
FileInputStream("secret_path_to_my.csv");
ObjectStream lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
ObjectStream sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);
int cutoff = 2;
int trainingIterations = 3;
model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", sampleStream, cutoff, trainingIterations);
```

Unfortunately, this is what I get:
Sorting and merging events... done. Reduced 1599474 events to 1579730.
Done indexing.
Incorporating indexed data for training...  
done.
Number of Event Tokens: 1579730
Number of Outcomes: 495970
Number of Predicates: 281447
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I already went to my Run Configurations in Eclipse and entered exactly the following in the VM section: "-Xmx16g" as my laptop has 16GB RAM.
Unfortunately, this only gets me some more seconds, before the program collapses, throwing the same error.

Please help me with locating the issue. I am not sure, whether decreasing the training set is the only option, or whether I am making some other mistakes. Thanks in advance!